# Enable Resolver logs in CM

Tags: sites-9.6, resolver, 9.6

I want to enable resolver logs because my resolver fails with the following exception during render phase:

```
Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveException: The error occured during Data Pipeline resolving. ---> System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead.
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.ConstructDocument(Object dataSource, String uriRelative, Uri uriResolved)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext..ctor(XmlQueryRuntime runtime, Object defaultDataSource, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argList, WhitespaceRuleLookup wsRules)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryRuntime..ctor(XmlQueryStaticData data, Object defaultDataSource, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argList, XmlSequenceWriter seqWrt)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XmlWriter results)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.XhtmlField.ApplyXslt(String value, XslCompiledTransform xslTransform)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.XhtmlField.ApplyXslts(String value)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.XhtmlField.ApplyFilterXslt(String valueToTransform, List`1 synchronizationActions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.XhtmlField.AddFieldValue(Object value, List`1 synchronizationActions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.ItemField.ReadFromElement(XmlNodeList fieldNodes)
```

How can i do that? Or has anyone got any info on what is this exception about.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the publishing service and running it from the command line with -debug?

Comment: I think I say this a lot… running the publisher in debug is eye-opening and really shows a lot of what’s happening “behind the scenes”.